# Evict not working in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

I have a method that fetches all the data and i am caching the result of that method but i am not able to evict the result.

```
@Component("cacheKeyGenerator")
public class CacheKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        final List<Object> key = new ArrayList<>();
        key.add(method.getDeclaringClass().getName());
        return key;
    }
}
```

CachedMethod:-

```
 @Override
        @Cacheable(value="appCache",keyGenerator="cacheKeyGenerator")
        public List<Contact> showAllContacts() {
            return contactRepository.findAll();
        }

    @Override
        @CachePut(value="appCache",key="#result.id")
        public Contact addData(Contact contact) {
            return contactRepository.save(contact);
        }
```

Now when ever addData is called i want the data in the cache "appCache" with the key ="cacheKeyGenerator" to be evicted.So that the data returned by the method "showAllContacts()" is accurate.Can anyone please help!

The Entire code can be found at - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/SpringCaching

Comment: use another method `@CacheEvict` to remove the cached entry? Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Looking at your current implementation raises one question: do you expect to evict the cache when calling `add(...)` because you are explicitly calling the empty (but annotated) method `evictCache()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a known constant cache key for `showAllContacts` then the solution should be to simply add `@CacheEvict` on `addData` passing in the cache name and key value:

```
@Override
@Caching(
    put = {@CachePut(value="appCache", key="#result.id")},
    evict = {@CacheEvict(cacheNames="appCache", key="someConstant")}
)
public Contact addData(Contact contact) {
    return contactRepository.save(contact);
}
```

However because you use a key generator it is a bit more involved. Now given what your key generator does, you could instead pick a value for that cache key, making sure there can't be any collisions with the values from `#result.id` and use that value instead of a the key generator returned one.